# Nested DataGrid in .NET Compact Framework 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid, compact-framework, master-detail

Is this possible? I'd like to display a list of Item Types and quantities that can then be expanded or collapsed with + and - ; when expanded they will show a number of rows of Items (and their statuses) associated with that Item Type.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need more a TreeView-Grid Hybrid, such control, union of TreeView and DataGrid, exists usually for windows forms, see here: [DevExpress winforms](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/#ctl00_ctl00_Content_Content_ctl32|2) . I am not aware of CF versions of it from any vendor.

Comment: Yeah that hybrid is exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for, but it doesn't look like it's for CF. Is there any way of adding this functionality to the stock DataGrid control? Or am I opening a massive can of worms there?

Comment: Be careful about cans of worms i'm trying to remember if they ever got round to making the datagrid read/write in CF (it was always read only in previous versions of CF). The DevExpress components are certainly nowhere near CF compatible IIRC.